# ASP.NET core get count from a table using raw query

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

How do I run a raw query in ASP.NET core to return the row count from a table?

Currently, I am doing this and the returned result is -1. I think the return result is based on the number of records affected.

```
 int numberOfRows = await
                    appDbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync(
                        $"SELECT CODE FROM [samaster] WHERE CODE={productBrandCode} AND WAREHOUSE={warehouse} ");
```

Any idea on how to get the count back to numberOfRows variable will be appreciated.

NOTE: The above table is not a model so I need to run a raw query.

Thanks

Comment: Please mark the answer as an accepted if it was helpful or comment it if-else.

Answer (score 1):

It is currently not possible to get the query result when using ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync. The same applies to any additional LINQ Statements.

You can, however, use the underlying ADO.net Provider:

```cs
    public IList<IDictionary<string, dynamic>> SelectDynamic(string table)
    {
        using (var command = Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = $"SELECT * FROM [{table}]";
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            Database.OpenConnection();

            using (var result = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                var entities = new List<IDictionary<string, dynamic>>();

                while (result.Read())
                {
                    var dict = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < result.FieldCount; i++)
                    {
                        dict.Add(result.GetName(i), result.GetValue(i));
                    }

                    entities.Add(dict);
                }

                return entities;
            }
        }
    }
```

Add this to your DbContext Class and Call it with:

```cs
using (var context = new MyDbContext()) // Or get it with DI, depends on your application
{
     var count = context.SelectDynamic("samaster").Where(d => d["CODE"] == productBrandCode && d["WAREHOUSE"] == warehouse).Count();
}
```

Beware, however, that this is an expensive operation if you have a lot of rows in your table! 
An alternative approach to only fetch the relevant results would be to replace

```cs
command.CommandText = $"SELECT * FROM [{table}]";
```

with

```cs
command.CommandText = $"SELECT CODE FROM [samaster] WHERE CODE={productBrandCode} AND WAREHOUSE={warehouse}";
```

and pass the parameters as function parameters.

```cs
public IList<IDictionary<string, dynamic>> SelectDynamic(string productBrandCode, string warehouse)
    {...
```

**Also make sure to escape all parameters if they are in any way submitted by user input to prevent SQL Injection Attacks!**

Comment: Yes, I end up using the Command Syntax. Strangely enough, there is nothing built in to do this.

Answer (score 0):

There are two common approaches :

A.

```
int numberOfRows = await appDbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync($"SELECT CODE FROM [samaster] WHERE CODE={productBrandCode} AND WAREHOUSE={warehouse} ").Count();
```

B.

```
int numberOfRows = await appDbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync($"SELECT count(*) FROM [samaster] WHERE CODE={productBrandCode} AND WAREHOUSE={warehouse} ").First();
```

Comment: I think you should explicitly point out that this code is only safe from sql injection when the string interpolation is done directly as part of passing the query-parameter to ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync. When you interpolate the string before by storing in a separate variable, this code will be vulnerable.

Comment: Isn't the above query sql injection safe in the question?

Comment: @XAMT I don't have any method called Cout() or First()

Comment: @Bikram; Add `using System.Linq;`

Comment: @XAMT I don't know if you tested your code or not. But using System.Linq does not solve the Count method on mine

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody gave me the correct answer. I end up using the following.

```
public async Task<bool> IsAValidProduct(string productBrandCode)
        {
            int count = 0;
            await using DbCommand command = appDbContext.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText =
                "SELECT COUNT(CODE) FROM [samaster] WHERE CODE=@productBrandCode AND WAREHOUSE=@warehouse ";
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@productBrandCode", SqlDbType.VarChar)
                {Value = productBrandCode});

            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@warehouse", SqlDbType.VarChar)
                {Value = warehouse});
            await appDbContext.Database.OpenConnectionAsync();

            count = (int) await command.ExecuteScalarAsync();

            await appDbContext.Database.CloseConnectionAsync();
            return count == 1;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

int c= dbObj.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(sql); //User this code

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31914829)